# How to update StreamNotifier (from riverpod) state when modifying data in firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, riverpod, state-management

I'm working on an app in flutter utilising riverpod for state management and firebase's realtime DB for database.

This is the code i've written for a streamnotifier which fetches data from firebase and sets the state as a stream of a model class called Pack.

```
class PackStreamNotifier extends StreamNotifier<List<Pack>> {
  late DatabaseReference _dbRef;

  PackStreamNotifier() : super() {
    _dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('packages');
  }

  @override
  Stream<List<Pack>> build() {
    return fetchData();
  }

  Stream<List<Pack>> fetchData() async* {
    List<Pack> packs = [];
    try {
      final data = await _dbRef.once().then((value) => value.snapshot);
      for (var dataNode in data.children) {
        Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = dataNode.value as Map;
        map.putIfAbsent('id', () => dataNode.key);
        //formatIntoPack method formats the map into model class (Pack).
        packs.add(formatIntoPack(map));
      }
      yield packs;
      state = AsyncValue.data(packs);
    } catch (error) {
      throw Exception('failed to fetch data');
    }
  }

  /* Editing an individual pack in firebase realtime DB. Doesn't work as intended */
  Stream<List<Pack>> editRecord(packId, Map<String, Object> updatedData) {
    _editPack(packId, updatedData);
    return fetchData();
  }

  void _editPack(packId, Map<String, Object> updatedData) {
    await _dbRef.child(packId).update(updatedData);
  }

  /* Deleting an entry from firebase. This works perfectly fine */
  void deleteRecord(packId) {
    _deletePack(packId);
    AsyncValue<List<Pack>> data = state;
    data.whenData((value) => value.removeWhere((pack) => pack.id == packId));
    state = data;
  }

  void _deletePack(packId) async {
    await _dbRef.child(packId).remove();
  }

  /* Creating a new entry in firebase. This works perfectly fine */
  void insertRecord(pack) {
    insert(pack);
    AsyncValue<List<Pack>> data = state;
    data.whenData((value) => value.add(pack));
    state = data;
  }

  void insert(pack) async {
    await _dbRef.push().set(pack);
  }
}

final PackProvider = StreamNotifierProvider<PackStreamNotifier, List<Pack>>(
    PackStreamNotifier.new);
```

Problem :- In editing a firebase entry, i want to utilise the fetchData method to revise the state. I don't want to manually set the state as I've done with deleting and creating records in firebase. But the fetchData won't get called from editRecord method.

Observation :- Data in the firebase realtime DB gets updated successfully. But the list of packs still reflects the old data. Whereas, a/c to my interpretation of the code I wrote, the state i.e. the list of packs will obtain the latest snapshot from firebase and should therefore affect the data. (But it doesn't).

Argument :- In the build method also, i'm calling fetchData and returning the results. That works fine when the state is first needed in the App. I'm using the same statement in editRecord with same expectations which are that the state will be revised but it doesn't. I'm not sure what am i missing here.

The code of widget using the editRecord method is as follows :-

```
class PackRecord extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const WeightRecord({super.key});
  final Pack pack;
  @override
  ConsumerState<PackRecord> createState() => _PackRecordState();
}

class _PackRecordState extends ConsumerState<PackRecord> {

  void onPressEdit() async {
    // Ui code here to display an editing alert dialog box. when the user clicks OK, editValue function below is invoked. The code was too large to fit in here but is a simple alert dialog box, so it seems fitting to skip code.
  }

  void editValue(int weight, context) async {
    final newPack = {'weight': weight};
    ref.read(PackProvider.notifier).editRecord(widget.pack.id, newPack);
    setState(() {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Track your weight'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              onPressEdit();
            },
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.mode_edit_outline_outlined,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      // Skipping the body since it isn't relevant to the problem mentioned.
    );
  }
}
```